# net.Listen returns errno -89 on linux/mipsle

Tags: go, mips

I'm running into an error with Go not being able to listen on a MIPSLE router. A simple listener using `net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")`

Is returning `Error listening: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: errno -89`

C compiled programs work fine, it seems to be just Go. I'm compiling with version 1.10.8 (1.11+ does not run on the router)

`env GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle GOMIPS=softfloat go build -a main.go`

Comment: Side note: unless you have very specific requirements, `go build` should normally not be used with file names but with package names (or empty or `.` for the package in the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23446

Issue with socket flags on older kernel versions. Resolved in GO 1.11+